# How to tell java to wait for an object to contain value

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

```
private FolderObjectItem currentFolder;

public void deleteFolder() {
    CaseFolderDAO caseFolderDAO = (CaseFolderDAO) Component.getInstance(
            CaseFolderDAO.COMPONENT_NAME, true);
    if (caseFolderDAO.deleteFolder(currentFolder.getFolderObjectID())) {
```

I know it's a norm in java to check for a variable if it contains a value before you can use it on your method. The code executes fine for list of records like < 100 of count but when it grows to like > 500, `currentFolder.getFolderObjectID()` always returns `NullPointerException`. Is there a way tell my method to wait for this object to contain a value before proceeding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you assign anything to currentFolder? Without more context, I'm not sure that your question can be answered in any specific way.

Comment: Myself, I'd say "use a call-back" but I'll be damned if I could figure out how to give anything much more specific than this based on what you've posted so far.

Comment: Im gonna need the currentFolder to get the ID of the currently-selected folder for when deletion action is executed on that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into the concept of futures.

In short, a Future allows asynchronous execution of code but crucially (which is what I think you want) will pause / block execution of code until the result of the future is available.

i.e.

```
doSomeStuff();
Future future = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
     public Integer call() {
         //code to get Folder Object ID
         //will execute in it's own thread
     }
});
continueDoingStuff();
Integer folderId = future.get(); //Could pause here or return imidiately. Depends if the "call()" method has finished.
continueOnceFolderIdIsReturned();
```